# c/c++/objective-c library for encoding mpegs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am looking to encode a jpg sequence into an mpeg format on an iphone project I am working on.  My google searches are coming up pretty short.  Does anyone happen to know of a library that would let me do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at ffmpeg

(more characters required)